# Apache Spark standalone cluster network troubles

Tags: apache-spark

I have ubuntu server on azure cloud with installed **spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6** on it. I want to start standalone cluster.

I am starting master by executing `./start-master.sh -h 10.0.0.4`(it's internal ip) and after that can access web-ui in http://[master-public-ip]:8080

Next, i also have ubuntu server as a slave in different network. I start it by `./start-slave.sh spark://[master-public-ip]:7077`. I can see successfully registered slave in master web-ui.

When i submit application on master with the following command:

```
   ./spark-submit --class com.MyClass --deploy-mode client \
    --master spark://[master-public-ip]:7077 \
    /home/user/my_jar.jar
```

I am getting the following error in slave web-ui:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.4:33742
```

So, master can connect to slave, but slave doesn't. How can i change configuration to slave was connected to master through public ip?

Setting SPARK_MASTER_IP to public ip doesn't work.

Comment: The master connects to workers on a random port, as documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html). The firewall is probably blocking this port range.

Comment: @DNA Firewall is disabled. I guess slave has wrong master ip.

Comment: OK - possibly the master is passing its internal IP to the slave upon registration or job creation? Just a guess, but perhaps the `start-master` script needs to be given the public IP not the internal one?

Comment: Also, running on public cloud without firewall sounds pretty risky - why do you need the master and slave to be on different networks?

Comment: @DNA I tried this way, but i was getting the error - java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service sparkMaster failed after 16 retries!

Comment: can you telnet from slave to master by master's private ip? I'd suggest that you need to start slave while specifying masters private ip(at least I'm doing so in AWS). Same for submitting parameter(assuming you are submitting from master itself)

Comment: @IgorBerman telnet doesn't work because master and slave in different networks.

Comment: Can you try to submit from slave? I think error you are getting might be that worker can't connectect to driver(which must be in same network as slaves)

Comment: @IgorBerman this approach can solve the problem when i have 1 slave, but if add one more slave which also sits in different network the problem appears again

Comment: @Nail, I might be wrong since I'm not developing spark, but imho you can't have slaves in different networks. You might try to solve it with creating VPN for all slaves(i.e. building this shared "network" manually)